# Where change background color remote host in PhpStorm?

Tags: colors, phpstorm

Where change background color remote host in PhpStorm?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color can't be changed, it's hardcoded (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103079). Feel free to submit a request to add an option to customize the color